# Any good library to parse common form fields in php?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, forms

So here I am, writing an app, creating a form with some very standard input fields like email, website, facebook, twitter, etc. and now I want to parse them all and check that the website input correctly begins with http(s)://, that the facebook link begins with http(s)://www.facebook.com, and so on.

So, I was wondering if you would know any library that would implement those functions nicely, I could reuse? I know it is quite common for email parsing for instance, so it must exist for general purpose, no?

As mentioned, php is my language, and cake is my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) and its [Zend_Validate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html) (and maybe also [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html)) component. Other libraries/frameworks propably have similar components, but I dont know them very well ;)

For a more low-level access to your problem, you can also look at PHPs own [validate filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

Comment: I guess the php validate filters will do, thx for the hint :)